# How do I update existing values and append new values to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have N dataframes, from each of which I'm extracting `df['col'].value_counts()` and converting these to a dictionary so I have:
`my_dict = {'key1' : val1, 'key2' : val2, ... , 'keyM' : valM}`

How do I update `my_dict` so that:
If a random new dataframe D has the same key as a previous dataframe (e.g. `'key1'`), then it adds the value to val1. In other words, if `'key1'` had a value of 21 and the new dataframe has a value of 18 for the same key (`'key1'`) , the dictionary key value should now be `'key1' : 39`.

If however, the key does not exist, then it should create a new key with the relevant value.

Does that make sense? I feel like I'm overcomplicating this...

Answer (score 4):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is built for this.

```
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter(my_dict)
c2 = Counter(my_other_dict)
c_sum = c1 + c2
```

On the other hand, you should be able to do this within pandas too; `value_counts()` returns a `Series` which you should be able to [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html#pandas.Series.add) to other `Series` objects directly and have it behave how you expect.

Comment: Also note that `Counter.update()` adds to the current counts (as opposed to `dict.update()` which overwrites). So you could initialize an empty counter, then update it in a for-loop that iterates over the N DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the key/values of new keys and update `my_dict`.  You should also look into using `defaultdict` from the collections module

```
my_dict = {'key1': 21, 'key2': 10}
my_dict2 = {'key1': 18, 'key3': 5}

for k, v in my_dict2.items():
    if k in my_dict:
        my_dict[k] += v
    else:
        my_dict[k] = v
```

Using defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(int, {'key1': 21, 'key2': 10})
my_dict2 = {'key1': 18, 'key3': 5}

for k, v in my_dict2.items():
    my_dict[k] += v
```

Comment: Hi James. Many thanks for this! I just tried out your first version and it works like a charm - thank you!

Could you please tell me a bit more about the rationale for the int in defaultdict?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer that uses `collections` as well:

```py
from collections import defaultdict as ddict

some_list_of_dicts = [
    {'val1': 5, 'val2': 3},
    {'val1': 2, 'val2': 1, 'val3': 9},
]

my_dict = ddict(int)

for i in some_list_of_dicts:
    for key, count in i.items():
        my_dict[key] += count

print(dict(my_dict))
```

A `defaultdict` of `int` will be initialised to 0 when an unknown key is introduced.

Comment: Cheers @Thomas!